# How can I know the total size taken by specific kind of files in my hard drive?

Tags: find, disk-usage, images

I would like to know if there's a command that can tell me how much storage are the .jpg files (for example). Something like if I do `find / -iname "*.jpg"` which can add the size of each file found and output a total.

Comment: Output the `find` results in a file an run `du -s` on its content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find ./path/to/your/drive -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} +
```

Or much faster

```
find /path/to/your/drive -name "*.jpg" -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

Or simply,

```
du -ch /path/to/your/drive/*.jpg | grep total
```

Or with help of `awk`,

```
find /path/to/your/drive -iname "*.jpg" -ls | awk '{total += $7} END {print total}'
```

On my system file size shows on seventh field, if it's different for you then adjust accordingly.

As requested by OP in comment, if you want to find all images from a directory and total size you can use this command (suggested by @Stéphane Chazelas)

```
 find . -type f -exec file --mime-type {} + | sed -n 's|: image/[^[:blank:]]*$||p' | tr '\n' '\0' | du --files0-from=- -hc
```

Or

```
 du -shc $(find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image' | cut -d':' -f1) | grep total
```

Comment: That will only give the individual sizes of each file.

Comment: @julipelletier typo corrected

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I just wonder how can I make it work with: `find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'` which basically looks for all images not just jp*g files.

Comment: @Saul, `find . -type f -exec file --mime-type {} + | sed -n 's|: image/[^[:blank:]]*$||p' | tr '\n' '\0' | du --files0-from=- -hc`

Comment: @Saul see updated answer

Comment: Please consider accepting answer which helped by clicking on right mark below up/down arrow.

Comment: I always get this: `0 total` as the output of what @StéphaneChazelas suggested.

Comment: And the second command is the only one I can get the grand total, and it's the one I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can do this using only POSIX:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec du -sk {} \; |
  awk 'BEGIN{total=0};{total += $1}; END{printf "%.3f MB\n", total / 1024}'
```

Further reading:

- [du - estimate file space usage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) (POSIX)
- [find - find files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (POSIX)

Comment: (about `;`) That's a POSIX requirement. I [tried to have that requirement lifted](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226)  as I couldn't find any implementation where it was needed, but [that was rejected by the gawk maintainer](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226#c2226).